# JS Tree links not active

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

I am new to Jquery and JS Tree but learning to love it. I have set
up a tree menu using php generated xml (see code below). It works as
expected with one exception - The links are not active.

I know there is something basic I don't understand. Short term I just
want the links to function as normal links. Long term I want them to
trigger an ajax call that will reload a specific div on the page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks much for the help!

```
$(function () {
        $("#mainMenu").jstree({
                xml_data : { data : <?php $menu->deliver(); ?> },
                core : { animation : 1000 }
                ui : { select_limit : 1, selected_parent_close : false },
                themes : { theme : "default", dots : true, icons : false },
                types : { types : { "heading" : { select_node : true } } },
                plugins : [ "themes", "xml_data", "ui", "types" ]
        });
});
```

Example xml (single item):

```
"<root><item id='pubPages_home' parent_id='0'><content><name href='?
a=pubPages&amp;f=home'>Public Home</name></content></item><root>"
```

Comment: What links don't work? If you click the node name? What do you want to happen? Could you provide jsfiddle sample?

Comment: @Radek The nodes do work (open and close the tree) as expected. The a tag hrefs don't function. When hovering over the links, the browser recognizes them, but clicking does not send the browser to the link. I suspect JS Tree has invoked preventDefault() for click on the a tags.

Answer (score 16):

```
            .bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                var href = data.node.a_attr.href
                document.location.href = href;
            }) ;
```

jstree version: "3.0.0",
jquery: last

**update:**
or best way for me:

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
  $('#jstree').jstree('save_state');
 }) ;

.on("activate_node.jstree", function(e,data){
   window.location.href = data.node.a_attr.href;
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I came here looking for a quick fix.  Lubor Bílek is mostly correct, but bear in mind that jsTree will bind the parent `<li>` of the clicked anchor element.

I solved this by doing:

```
.bind('select_node.jstree', function(e,data) { 
    window.location.href = data.rslt.obj.find('a').attr("href"); 
});
```

That way, the event will bind to the child `<a>` of the `<li>` instead of the `<li>` itself, so that you can have the href attribute on your anchors instead of your list items.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to explicitly write the click handler for the tree node links. JsTree takes the click event for itself and do not let it go to redirect page.

I would try to go this way:

```
$('#mainMenu').bind('select_node.jstree', function(e,data) { 
    window.location.href = data.rslt.obj.attr("href"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved right now this problem with a little brute force

```
<li id="child_node_1"><span onClick="javascript:window.location.href='your_page.html'" title="Lassie come home!">your text here</span></li>
```

nice and easy.

Answer (score 1):

I try this code:

```
window.location.href = data.rslt.obj.find('a').attr("href");
```

It raise data.rslt undefined error, so I can not get href with it!

here is my available code:

```
$("#mytree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
  window.location.href = data.node.a_attr.href;
});
```

Is related to the version of jstree? My jstree version: 3.0.0-bata10

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#mytree ul").on("click","li.jstree-node a",function(){
    document.location.href = this; 
});
```

Thanks to [jQuery event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) , this event will delegate to `<a>` elemets .
if you doesn't use event delegation it will fire just for first time you click each anchor.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Can you provide an explanation that will benefit the OP as well as future visitors to SO?

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple way.

```
$('#'+target).jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : treeInfo
} });

$(".jstree-anchor").click(function()
{
    document.location.href = this; 
});
```

I found that the jstree used the "jstree-anchor" class for the li lists.
So, I can find href link from the this object, I can make this link without any bounding functions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we need to control the action of both "Container Nodes" and "Child Nodes" together.

So we can do thomething like :

```
$("#jstree-div").jstree().delegate("a","click", function(e) {
            if ($("#jstree-div").jstree("is_leaf", this)) {
                document.location.href = this;
            }
            else {
                $("#jstree-div").jstree("toggle_node", this);
            }
        });
```

"is_leaf" is one of jsTree functions that checks if a node has no children.